# Detecting a drag operation from another application

Tags: c#, c++, windows, drag-and-drop

I have an application that runs elevated (yes, it has to be elevated) but it needs to detect when another application is dragging an object over it. My application doesn't care what the object is, it doesn't want to receive the object, it just needs to know if something is being dragged. In a normal application this isn't an issue, but because my application is elevated it doesn't receive any of the standard drag/drop events from lower privilege applications. Is there a programmatic way to detect whether the cursor is involved in a drag/drop operation?

Answer (score 0):

To do "system wide" drag and drop, I think you have to go the OLE way.

[Drag and Drop (OLE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96826a87%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Also see the "Data Objects and Data Sources (OLE)" link at the bottom of the article.